# APIM 4.2.0 taking too long to start, it was looping through, StartupFinalizerServiceComponent Waiting for required OSGi services

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-api-manager

TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:04:51,417]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.ApplicationAuthenticationService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl

This is getting looped again and again , its been more than 2 hours .Still its apim not up, am starting in foreground.

```
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:13:49,923]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.inbound.InboundEndpoint} - Initializing Inbound Endpoint: SecureWebhookServer
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:13:49,966]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.core.PassThroughListeningIOReactorManager} - Pass-through SecureWebhookServer Listener started on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:8022
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:13:49,970]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.api.API} - {api:_OpenService_} Initializing API: _OpenService_
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:13:49,971]  INFO {org.apache.synapse.ServerManager} - Server ready for processing...
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:13:50,827]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.websocket.management.WebsocketEndpointManager} - Netty Listener already started on port 8100
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:13:50,827]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.http.management.HTTPEndpointManager} - Listener is already started for port : 8022
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:13:50,827]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.websocket.management.WebsocketEndpointManager} - Netty Listener already started on port 9100
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:13:50,827]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.inbound.endpoint.protocol.http.management.HTTPEndpointManager} - Listener is already started for port : 9022
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:13:51,134]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.andes.utils.MessageBrokerDBUtil} - Message Broker database store already exists. Not creating a new database.
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:13:51,135]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.andes.utils.MessageBrokerDBUtil} - Successfully sourced relevant sql files to database.
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:13:51,135]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.andes.internal.QpidServiceComponent} - Activating Andes Message Broker Engine...
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:13:52,060]  INFO {qpid.message.broker.listening} - [Broker] BRK-1002 : Starting : Listening on TCP port 5673
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:13:52,074]  INFO {qpid.message.broker.listening} - [Broker] BRK-1002 : Starting : Listening on TCP/SSL port 8673
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:13:52,083]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.andes.internal.QpidServiceComponent} - AMQP Host Address : 0.0.0.0 Port : 5673
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:13:52,083]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.andes.internal.QpidServiceComponent} - Successfully connected to AMQP server on port 5673
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:13:52,084]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.andes.internal.QpidServiceComponent} - WSO2 Message Broker is started.
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:13:53,585]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} - Mgt Console URL  : https://localhost:9444/carbon/
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:13:53,586]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} - API Developer Portal Default Context : https://localhost:9444/devportal
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:13:53,586]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ui.internal.CarbonUIServiceComponent} - API Publisher Default Context : https://localhost:9444/publisher
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:14:15,331]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.ApplicationAuthenticationService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityCoreInitializedEvent,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl,
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:15:15,324]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.ApplicationAuthenticationService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityCoreInitializedEvent,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl,
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:16:15,335]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.ApplicationAuthenticationService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityCoreInitializedEvent,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl,
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:17:15,327]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.ApplicationAuthenticationService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityCoreInitializedEvent,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl,
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:18:15,325]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.ApplicationAuthenticationService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityCoreInitializedEvent,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl,
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:19:15,322]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.ApplicationAuthenticationService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityCoreInitializedEvent,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl,
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:20:15,326]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.ApplicationAuthenticationService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityCoreInitializedEvent,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl,
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:21:15,325]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.ApplicationAuthenticationService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityCoreInitializedEvent,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl,
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:22:15,328]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.ApplicationAuthenticationService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityCoreInitializedEvent,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl,
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:23:15,322]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.ApplicationAuthenticationService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityCoreInitializedEvent,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl,
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:24:15,335]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.ApplicationAuthenticationService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityCoreInitializedEvent,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl,
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:25:15,337]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.ApplicationAuthenticationService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityCoreInitializedEvent,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl,
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:26:15,332]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.ApplicationAuthenticationService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityCoreInitializedEvent,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl,
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:27:15,328]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.ApplicationAuthenticationService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityCoreInitializedEvent,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl,
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:28:15,333]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.ApplicationAuthenticationService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityCoreInitializedEvent,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl,
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:29:15,326]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.ApplicationAuthenticationService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityCoreInitializedEvent,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl,
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:30:15,336]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.ApplicationAuthenticationService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityCoreInitializedEvent,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl,
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:31:15,322]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.ApplicationAuthenticationService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityCoreInitializedEvent,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl,
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:32:15,329]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.ApplicationAuthenticationService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityCoreInitializedEvent,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl,
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:33:15,333]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.ApplicationAuthenticationService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityCoreInitializedEvent,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl,
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:34:15,322]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.ApplicationAuthenticationService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityCoreInitializedEvent,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl,
TID: [] [] [2024-02-09 19:35:15,324]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.StartupFinalizerServiceComponent} - Waiting for required OSGi services: org.wso2.carbon.identity.application.authentication.framework.ApplicationAuthenticationService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.core.util.IdentityCoreInitializedEvent,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2ScopeService,org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.OAuthAdminServiceImpl,
```

Comment: What is your OS and JDK version?

Comment: Also was this server running before? If so what changes did you do before this weeoe?

Comment: windows 11 and jdk verison is 11

Comment: Was checking with apim 4.2.0 (started as foreground) using apimanager.bat in order to run windows machine